# How to use USB debugging "by air"?

Tags: adb

On my PC is installed Android Studio and ADB. I can connect with Android via a USB wire. But in the settings there is a function

[image: screenshot]

where can I write 0.0.0.0:5555 to connect to a PC by air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP. Mobile carriers don't expose IP addresses for external connection.

Instead, connect to a WiFi network which your PC is also connected to. Then turn on the option, after which you should see a valid local IP address. On your PC, run `adb connect your.local.ip.address:5555`, and provided that the network is properly set up (e.g. no firewall rules blocking access), you will be wirelessly connected to the device via ADB. Use `adb disconnect` when you're done with it.

More general info about `adb` (and how to do it wirelessly even if your device doesn't have that option in Developer Options) is available [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless).

Comment: Where i can see valid local IP address? In Wi-Fi menu

Comment: Turn WiFi on and come back to Developer Options. Think you should re-toggle "ADB over network" too if you left it on.

Comment: @AndyYan If one uses tethering, though, they'll be able to connect to the phone without an auxiliary Wi-Fi.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Hmm, right. Never used it that way so didn't think of it.

Comment: thanks, did. Very cool: D Just happened when I gave out WiFi from PC to phone, but not vice versa